# ¿Es correcto este iterador para la colección creada? o ¿debería simplificarlo?

Tags: java, iteradores

Quiero saber si es correcto el siguiente código para crear una colección de objetos y implementarle un iterador. Lo que se solicita es que la colección pueda ser de cualquier tipo de datos numéricos en java.

La colección si creo que esté bien, con el iterador es con el que no estoy muy seguro. A pesar de que supera los test, me gustaría simplificarlo.

```
package es.ubu.gii.edat.sesion02.generico;

import java.util.AbstractCollection;
 
public class ColeccionRango<T extends Number> extends AbstractCollection <T> {
    
    private final T inferior;
    private final T superior;
    private final T paso;
    private int size;
 
    public int size() {     
        return size;    
    }    
 
    public ColeccionRango(T inferior, T superior, T paso) {            
        double inferiorDouble = inferior.doubleValue();
        double superiorDouble = superior.doubleValue();
        double pasoDouble = paso.doubleValue();
        if (superiorDouble < inferiorDouble || pasoDouble > superiorDouble - inferiorDouble) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argumentos inválidos");
        }             
        this.inferior = inferior;
        this.superior = superior;
        this.paso = paso;             
        this.size = (int) Math.ceil((superior.doubleValue() - inferior.doubleValue()) / paso.doubleValue()); 
     }

  // TODO completar instanciación
     public Iterator<T> iterator() {
         return new Iterator<T>() {
             private double actual = inferior.doubleValue();

             public boolean hasNext() {
                 return actual < superior.doubleValue();
             }

             public T next() {
                 if (!hasNext()) {
                     throw new NoSuchElementException();
                 }
                 T resultado = null;
                 if (inferior instanceof Integer) {
                     resultado = (T) Integer.valueOf((int) actual);
                 } 
                 else if (inferior instanceof Double) {
                     resultado = (T) Double.valueOf(actual);
                 } 
                 else if (inferior instanceof Float) {
                     resultado = (T) Float.valueOf((float) actual);
                 } 
                 else if (inferior instanceof Long) {
                     resultado = (T) Long.valueOf((long) actual);
                 } 
                 else if (inferior instanceof Short) {
                     resultado = (T) Short.valueOf((short) actual);
                 }
                 actual += paso.doubleValue();
                 return resultado;
            }

            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Flavio, podrías agregar el resto de la clase, no logro entender lo que estas  haciendo...

Comment: Intento iterar una colección, que pueda ser de cualquier tipo de dato numérico.

Answer (score 0):

Intenté replicar tus métodos, no se si con mucho éxito, ya que no estoy seguro de haber entendido parte de la consigna.

Primero, crear un iterador, es tan fácil como:

```
List<Integer> numA = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator ite = numA.iterator();
```

Luego creas un bucle **while** e iteras así:

```
while( ite.hasNext() ) { 
    Integer inte = (Integer) ite.next();
    hagoLoQueSea();
}
```

Ahora bien, entiendo que recibes una colección, de números, y buscas devolver los valores que cumplan con la condición ***> inferior && < superior**, y aparte, con cada iteración, el valor de inferior se incrementa con **paso**.

```
void crea() {
   List<Number> numA = new ArrayList<>();
   numA.add( 100 );
   numA.add( 110 );
   numA.add( 115 );
   numA.add( 120 );
   numA.add( 122 );
   numA.add( 123 );
   numA.add( 124 );
   numA.add( 150 );
   List<Number> numB = new ArrayList<>();
   numB.add( 3.5 );
   numB.add( 28.0 );
   numB.add( 0.87 );
   numB.add( 1.1 );
   itera( numA, 100, 350, 5 );
   itera( numB, 1.0, 5.0, 2.2 );
}

void itera( List<Number> num, double inferior, double superior, double paso ) {
   Number pri = num.get( 0 );
   Iterator ite = num.iterator();
   double inferiorActualizado = inferior;
   while( ite.hasNext() ) {         
      if( pri instanceof Integer ) {
         Integer inte = (Integer) ite.next();
         if( inte > inferiorActualizado ) {
             System.out.println( inte );
         }
      }
      else if( pri instanceof Double ) {
         Double dou = (Double) ite.next();
         if( dou > inferiorActualizado ) {
             System.out.println( dou );
         }
      }
      else if( pri instanceof Float ) {
         Float flo = (Float) ite.next();
         if( flo > inferiorActualizado ) {
             System.out.println( flo );
         }
      }
      else if( pri instanceof Long ) {
         Long lon = (Long) ite.next();
         if( lon > inferiorActualizado ) {
             System.out.println( lon );
         }
      }
      else if( pri instanceof Short ) {
         Short sho = (Short) ite.next();
         if( sho > inferiorActualizado ) {
             System.out.println( sho );
         }
      }
      inferiorActualizado += paso;
   }
}
```